# Adsense Error 400 not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, adsense

im trying to show some ads in a test html page, the ads dont show and i get error GET 400.
Can someone help ?

my website : isrmicha.comli.com

```
<html>
<head>

<title>Exemplo de página HTML</title>
</head>
<body>

  <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- UpListMeme -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxxx"
     data-ad-slot="8702086429"
     data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fix it, just changed the script to this

```
   <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- YouWeb -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="xxxxxxxx"
     data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
<script>
```

and it worked!